# How can I import a json file into an angular component with axios?

Tags: json, angular, axios

I generated(ng-cli) an angular 5 app and created this component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import axios from 'axios';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    axios.get('./data.json')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  }
}
```

I am trying to import my json data into the component with axios.
When I run npm start I get this error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/data.json 404 (Not Found)

How can I import my json without issues?

Here is a link to [github](https://github.com/dimitri-a/importjson.git)

Comment: since you are using cli, you should place your JSON file in assets folder.

Comment: I am curious why not just use the built-in HTTP client?

Comment: What would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you put your json in the assets Folder or you modify the angular-cli.json and include your json under assets.

Comment: I put the data.json in the assets folder and updated the .angular-cli.json but still the same issue

Comment: When you update the angular-cli.json you need restart the server

Comment: I just did , no difference

Comment: If you did the json in the assets folder you need to chane the path to ./assets/data.json